# FreeTextTable bad performance with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, query-performance, freetexttable

My index is populated with 12 millions of rows from DatasSearch_fr table

Fields are :

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[DataId] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[DataTypeId] [int] NOT NULL
```

By using FREETEXTTABLE like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(DatasSearch_fr, (Data), 'din', LANGUAGE 1036) AS FT
```

Query returns 12 000 rows instantly

But by using  FREETEXTTABLE like this:

```
SELECT DataId, DataTypeId, MAX(Rank) as Rank FROM DatasSearch_fr
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(DatasSearch_fr, (Data), 'din', LANGUAGE 1036) AS FT ON FT.[Key] = Id
Group By DataId, DataTypeId
```

Query returns 4400 rows in 10 or 15 seconds...

Problem for me is not 4400 rows returned, this point is logically dûe to `Max(rank)` and `Group by`...But the 10 or 15 seconds seem very too much and this slowest response time is not always case with all keywords searched.

Do you know a way to improve this response time ?

Thanks for your help,
Sébastien

Comment: I have noticed in query execution plan that query which take 10 or 15 seconds used parallelism... I don't know why. Someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
set statistics io on
```

I have this result:

> Table 'DatasSearch_fr'. Scan count 5, logical reads 37861,
>    physical reads 0, read-ahead 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0,  physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0,
>   lob read-ahead reads 0.

If someone have an idea. :)

EDIT:
Below, Query Execution Plan

```
  |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
       |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataId], [DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataTypeId]), RESIDUAL:([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataId] = [DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataId] AND [DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataTypeId] = [DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataTypeId]) DEFINE:([Expr1007]=MAX(CONVERT(int,[Expr1005],0))))
            |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataId], [DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[DataTypeId]))
                 |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:(FulltextMatch.[docid])=([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[Id]))
                      |--Bitmap(HASH:(FulltextMatch.[docid]), DEFINE:([Bitmap1012]))
                      |    |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:(FulltextMatch.[docid]) DEFINE:([Expr1005]=MAX([Expr1004])))
                      |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:(FulltextMatch.[docid]), ORDER BY:(FulltextMatch.[docid] ASC))
                      |              |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:(FulltextMatch.[docid], FulltextMatch.[colid]) DEFINE:([Expr1004]=SUM([Expr1008])))
                      |                   |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=freetexttablerank((0),FulltextMatch.[termfrequency],FulltextMatch.[columnweight]*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),FulltextMatch.[documentlength],0),FulltextMatch.[columnweight]*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),FulltextMatch.[avdl],0),FulltextMatch.[termweight])))
                      |                        |--Parallelism(Distribute Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:(FulltextMatch.[docid], FulltextMatch.[colid]))
                      |                             |--Table-valued function
                      |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[Id]))
                           |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[IX_DatasSearch_fr_IdNew]),  WHERE:(PROBE([Bitmap1012],[DataBase].[dbo].[DatasSearch_fr].[Id],N'[IN ROW]')))
```